# Como adicionar legenda em um gráfico usando ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, html, chartjs

Criei o seguinte gráfico:

```js
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red",
        subtitle: "texto"
    },
    {
        value: 590,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 190,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Além disso, gostaria de adicionar legenda no gráfico, assim:

[image: inserir a de]

Mas não estou conseguindo achar como. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alterei apenas o final do seu código:

Inclui o [generateLegend()](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.0/docs/06-Advanced.md#generatelegend) para gerar uma legenda na nova `div` que adicionei (**legendDiv**).

[Aqui você consegue ler sobre a documentação do chart JS V1.](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/v1.1.0/docs)

```js
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red",
        subtitle: "texto"
    },
    {
        value: 590,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 190,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var grafico = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = grafico .generateLegend();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="legendDiv"></div>
```